# Concluding the general characteristic polynomial using finite field method

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields

Studying hyperplane arrangements in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, the finite field method is explained and (for completeness here) relies on the following theorem:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an arrangement in $\mathbb{Q}^n$, and suppose $L(\mathcal{A})\simeq L(\mathcal{A}_q)$ for some prime power $q$. Then $$\chi_\mathcal{A}(q)=\#\left(\mathbb{F}^n_q-\bigcup_{H\in\mathcal{A}_q}H\right).$$

Using this theorem is straightforward enough but there's a small detail I can't really grasp: in all examples Stanley applies the theorem to get some expression $\chi_\mathcal{A}(q)$ and then directly makes a conclusion of $\chi_\mathcal{A}(x)$ for *general* $x$. For me, $q$ is fixed although (slightly) arbitrary so $\chi_\mathcal{A}(q)$ is, you know, a value that happens to be a polynomial in $q$. It *feels like* drawing the conclusion that $f(x)=x^2+2x-1$ from knowing that $f(3)=14$. Is it because there's infinitely many such $q$'s? Something else?

I'm rather certain this has some combinatorics-flavored answer where the variable is there to more or less just keep different numbers apart (and evaluating functions at a specific point is more of a nice feature than the point of the procedure), but it's hard to be certain of your own thoughts with such things.

Comment: I should learn this! It seems to be that your question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4600008/11619), where the root system stuff simply says a lot more about the inherent symmetries of the hyperplane arrangement. Again  assuming that your question is about an arrangement of hyperplanes. But, this is mostly speculation by me.

Comment: Anyway (more speculation), it seems likely that we, indeed, get the same polynomial for most choices of prime $p$ (and $q$ a power of such a prime). In vaguely similar problems in number theory there are often only finitely many primes, where something exceptional happens. Comparing with the other question, I guess that this polynomial simply "counts" the numbers of hyperplanes of various dimensions gotten as intersections of the system. Of course, it is a live possibility that I'm way off base :-)

Comment: Another possibility is that if we know, from elsewhere in the theory, that the coefficients of $\chi$ are integers of bounded size, then some large enough input will uniquely identify it. For example, if we know that $\chi(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients of absolute value at most $3$, and that $\chi(1000)=1001999$, then we **can** conclude that $\chi(x)=x^2+2x-1$.

Comment: It's indeed about hyperplane arrangements! Stanley just shortens it to "arrangements" only. I think you're onto something with the boundedness of the coefficients – although I'm uncertain of exactly *how*. Per definition $\chi_{\mathcal{A}}(x)=\sum_{t\in L(\mathcal{A})}\mu(0,t)x^{dim(t)}$ (which is a handful) i.e. each coefficient is a finite sum of integers, since $\mu$ is integer-valued. I'll try to follow this trail somehow...